# How to edit ignored resources in Eclipse Kepler? (.cvsignore)

Tags: eclipse, cvs

How to edit or remove something from .cvsignore in newest Eclipse (Kepler)?

There is an easy way to ***add*** something to .cvsignore:

- open *Team Synchronizing* perspective
- right click on element, *Add to .cvsignore*

How can I reverse that? Some easy way of editing ingored list?

*Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Ignored Resources* isn't quite I looked for, there are only general rules, like `*.exe`, `*~`.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Navogator view (in contrast to the package explorer it shows all files, including .cvsignore) and open the .cvsignore file, edit manually.

Answer (score 0):

Close to the option *Add to .cvsignore...* there is also the option *Add to Version Control*, this should make the trick too.